# JavaFX FX application Thread Issue

Tags: multithreading, javafx, task

I'm doing a desktop application and I'm performing a heavy task in background. I want a progress bar to be updated. My program works and I can see the progress bar here isn't my problem. My problem is that I use 2 tasks that I run in 2 thread in order to make both the update of the progress bar and the heavy task. My question is : Is there a better way to do in oder to avoid the error "Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-5".

Of course I already check on Internet and I always find : better use Platform.runLater. Ok but in both new thread I need attribute of my class, eg I can't access for example "this.myAttribute" when I use Platform.runLater((new Runnable()...)). Is RunLater the solution and I can't see it ?

Here is a bunch of code, the method setConnection is called in JavaFX thread, and I create 2 other. One for progressbar, the other for my task :

```
@FXML
    private void setConnection() {
        try {
            this.onOffButton.setSelected(false);
            if (!this.hubModel.isConnected()) {
                this.progressBar.progressProperty().unbind();
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                OperationTask progressBarOperationTask = new OperationTask(this) {
                    @Override
                    public Void call() {
                        HubController hubController = (HubController) this.getHubController();
                        hubController.getProgressBar().setVisible(true);
                        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(25);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                Thread.interrupted();
                                break;
                            }
                            updateProgress(i + 1, 100);
                        }
                        hubController.getProgressBar().setVisible(false);
                        return null;
                    }
                };
                this.progressBar.progressProperty().bind(progressBarOperationTask.progressProperty());
                Thread timeThread = new Thread(progressBarOperationTask);
                timeThread.setDaemon(true);
                timeThread.start();
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            OperationTask connectionOperationTask = new OperationTask(this) {

                @Override
                protected Object call() throws Exception {
                    HubController hubController = (HubController) this.getHubController();
                    if (hubController.getUserID().getText().equals("") || hubController.getUserPW().getText().equals("")) {
                        hubController.getCommentBottom().setText("Please enter a user name and a password.");
                        hubController.getOnOffButton().setSelected(false);
                    } else {
                        hubController.getHubModel().setIdUser(hubController.getUserID().getText());
                        hubController.getHubModel().setPwUser(hubController.getUserPW().getText());
                        String comment = hubController.getHubModel().setConnection();
                        if (!comment.equals("Connection established.")) {
                            hubController.getOnOffButton().setSelected(false);
                        }
                        if (hubController.getHubModel().isConnected()) {
                            hubController.getConnectionStatus().setText("Connected");
                            hubController.getConnectionStatus().setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
                            String commentProject = hubController.getHubModel().getAllProjects();
                            if (commentProject.equals("")) {
                                TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(hubController.getCloneAndMoveController().getNewProjectNameTextField(), hubController.getHubModel().getProjectsList());
                            } else {
                                comment = commentProject;
                            }
                            hubController.getOnOffButton().setSelected(true);
                        } else {
                            hubController.getConnectionStatus().setText("Not connected");
                            hubController.getConnectionStatus().setStyle("-fx-font-weight: regular");
                        }
                        hubController.getCommentBottom().setText(comment);
                    }
                    return null;
                }

            };
            Thread connectionThread = new Thread(connectionOperationTask);
            connectionThread.setDaemon(true);
            connectionThread.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Moreover if you see something that could be improved, I would appreciate (I'm new with java)

Thank you.

Comment: It is hard to follow and answer without an example code. Please provide a [mcve]. The short answer is - there is no real alternative to `Platform.runLater`; the longer version is - you should only use `runLater` on the minimal piece of code that actually modifies the UI.

Comment: I would not agree with @Itai about the alternative, but strongly agree that you must provide MCVE to get any help.

Comment: @PrzemekKrysztofiak - what is the other option? Any change to the UI in JavaFX must be done on the FX thread - no matter how you do it, it is bound to be functionally almost identical to using `Platform.runLater`... or am I missing something?

Comment: Is that possible to have a copy of you code (not the entire cod but the part that you made with two thread) because, as @Itai said, it is very hard to help someone on a specific probleme if we can't se the problem.

Comment: @Itai there are other options: [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html), [Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) and [ScheduledService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html). For more Information read: [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm)

Comment: @Itai Sorry, you are right, I missunderstood the question. There is no alternative for Platform.runLater(). It was early in the morning when I read it.

Comment: Thank you both of you. I just edited my post.

Comment: you __must not__ access anything on the scenegraph off the fx application thread. No leeway, no way around. Period. And the sooner you provide a [mcve] as suggested above, the sooner you can expect help.

Answer (score 1):

You can access your object from `Platform.runLater()`. New `Runnable` which you create for it has access to `this` instance of your object. See in an example:

```
private String myAttribute = "hello";

@Override
public void randomMethod() {
    //...

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(myAttribute);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: start is guaranteed to run on the fx app thread .. invoking runlater does nothing additional (except deferring the access to some unspecified time "later-on"

Comment: @kleopatra the point of the example was just accessing myAttribute from the inner class. Also, it's not guaranteed: one can do `new Thread(()-> { new Application().start(null); })` and get it off the FX thread easily.

Comment: sure, there are many ways to kill oneself ;) Calling start off the fx application thread is a contract violation. Don't even think of it, much less suggest it to a newbie. -1

Comment: @kleopatra, hmm, but I suggested it to you, you doesn't sound like a newbie :)

Comment: your comment will be read by the OP (and other newbies) as well :)